# 4 JRadioButtons used in a ButtonGroup, selecting specific button with a numeric value

Tags: java, swing

I have built a UI with 4 radio buttons, and then grouped them together in a ButtonGroup.  I get the index of the button selected, and store it in a DB.  But when the form is displayed back, i am required to show which button was initially selected.  The following is the code i get to save the index value.

```
Enumeration<AbstractButton> elements = ProdType.getElements();
while (elements.hasMoreElements()) {
    AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) elements.nextElement();
    if (button.isSelected()) {
        if (button.getText().equals("ZERO"))
            strProdType = "0";
        else if (button.getText().equals("ONE"))
            strProdType = "1";
        else if (button.getText().equals("TWO"))
            strProdType = "2";
        else if (button.getText().equals("THREE"))
            strProdType = "3";
        else if (button.getText().equals("FOUR"))
            strProdType = "4";
    }
}
```

Comment: My first thought is, you could simply the code by making use of the `actionCommand` property of the `JButton`, which would mean, rather then going through the hassle of the `if` statement, you could just use `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` directly.  Obviously, though, you need to be able to match the value back to a button.  This would assume you have a reference to all the buttons, preferably in a `Map` of some kind

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes to the code shown above, and it now works perfect.  I am storing it as String value, and then using the same string value converted to integer while displaying. Some trouble faced cos of RadioButtons and the ButtonGroup.  But quite a learning.

```
Enumeration<AbstractButton> elements = MyType.getElements();
while (elements.hasMoreElements()) {
   AbstractButton button = elements.nextElement();
   if (button.isSelected()) {
      strMyTypeVal = Integer.toString(i);
   }
   i = i + 1;
}
```